# Why Bibliography and References appears in Latex TOC?

Tags: latex, biblatex

I am using these commands for including references:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}

\bibliographystyle{agsm}

\bibliography{dissrefs}
```

The problem is that in the table of contents both `References` and `Bibliography` appear, while I just want one to appear. Why is this happening? Can I customise the table of contents entry to be just one of them?

I am using MikTex 2.8 and TexMaker 2.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont think that you need to use `\addcontentsline{toc}` bibtex should do it automatically.  At least I don't recall ever needing it...

Have you tried commenting out that line?

**Edit** regarding OPs comment on changing the title of the bibliography:

The bibliography's title can be changed by (to for instance "New Title") using `\renewcommand\refname{New Title}` for articles and `\renewcommand\bibname{New Title}` for books.

Comment: Yes, Commenting the line solves the problem. How can I make the title of Bibliography to be "references" not Bibliography?

Comment: I am not quite sure but I think it might have to do with the bibliography style or the document type you use. I have been using article doc type in most of my documents, and the one I am looking at right now has "references" title. I hope it helps.. :s

Comment: oh here we go: The bibliography's title can be changed by using "\renewcommand\refname{New Title}" for articles and "\renewcommand\bibname{New Title}" for books.

Answer (score 0):

Instructions are read and processed in the order they appear, I think your problem is related to that order. Try moving things around (I believe that all settings should be put before \tableofcontents, but I'm not sure about that, I'v not used latex for a long time)